# R mapply to multiple matrices

Tags: r, matrix

Suppose I have three matrices

```
col1 <- matrix(rep(c(1,2),each=5),5,ncol=2)
col2 <- matrix(rep(c(3,4),each=5),5,ncol=2)
col3 <- matrix(rep(c(5,6),each=5),5,ncol=2)
```

I want to build a print function that prints

```
1. (1,2),(3,4),(5,6)
2. (1,2),(3,4),(5,6)
3. (1,2),(3,4),(5,6)
4. (1,2),(3,4),(5,6)
5. (1,2),(3,4),(5,6)
```

I was thinking about using mapply, but mapply returns individual values

```
mapply(function(a,b,c) {print(paste(a,b,c))},col1,col2,col3)
[1] "1 3 5" "1 3 5" "1 3 5" "1 3 5" "1 3 5" "2 4 6" "2 4 6" "2 4 6" "2 4 6" "2 4 6"
```

Basically, I want to handle each row of the matrix as a group, but I can't quite figure out how.

I know I could do this with a for loop but I'm trying to avoid this.

TiA.

Edit - it's not really about print formatting, it's about using each row of each matrix as set of vector inputs.

e.g.

```
Compare <- function(x,y,z) {
  return(x * 6 > (y + z))
}

for(i in 1:nrow(col1)) {
  print(Compare(col1[i,],col2[i,],col3[i,]))
}

[1] FALSE  TRUE
[1] FALSE  TRUE
[1] FALSE  TRUE
[1] FALSE  TRUE
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I have multiple matrices of the same size that I want to pass to a function. Each row in each matrix represents an input.

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to achieve. Just `Compare(col1,col2,col3)` works to produce the desired output, since vectorization.

Comment: Another way would be to transpose the matrices and convert them to data.frames. `mapply` should work.

Answer (score 2):

If this is really all about print formatting, here is a function that should work. We use `paste()` to combine the elements into strings and use `apply()` to  apply functions across rows of your matices

```
foo <- function(..., .dots=list()) {
    dots<-c(list(...), .dots)
    x <- apply(sapply(dots, function(x) 
         paste0("(", apply(x,1,paste,collapse=","), ")")),
         1, paste, collapse=",")
    paste0(1:length(x), ". ", x, collapse="\n")
}

cat(foo(col1,col2,col3))
# 1. (1,2),(3,4),(5,6)
# 2. (1,2),(3,4),(5,6)
# 3. (1,2),(3,4),(5,6)
# 4. (1,2),(3,4),(5,6)
# 5. (1,2),(3,4),(5,6)
```

or

```
cat(foo(.dots=list(col1,col2,col3)))
```

Comment: it's not really about print formatting, it's about using each row of each matrix as set of vector inputs. please see my edit. i basically want to use mapply() on matrices by row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Map() function.

Try the following:

```
f1 <- function(x) paste("(", paste(as.character(x), collapse = ","), ")", sep="")
f2 = unlist(Map(function(x) paste(x, ". ", paste(f1(col1[x,]), f1(col2[x,]), f1(col3[x,]), sep = ","), sep = ""), 1:nrow(col1)))
cat(f2, sep="\n")
```

This gives the desired output:

```
1. (1,2),(3,4),(5,6)
2. (1,2),(3,4),(5,6)
3. (1,2),(3,4),(5,6)
4. (1,2),(3,4),(5,6)
5. (1,2),(3,4),(5,6)
```